# Does $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {\sqrt {2n-1}~ \log (4n+1)} {n(n+1)}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {\sqrt {2n-1}~ \log (4n+1)} {n(n+1)}$ converge?

**Attempt:** I have been trying to use the comparison test for a while, but I can't find a suitable comparator.

For Example, since, $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac {1}{n(n+1)}$ converges, I was thinking of an expression involving the above to use as a comparator. But can not find one.

Please guide me on how to move ahead.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First using the L'Hôpital's rule we see that

$$\ln(n)=_\infty o(n^\alpha),\quad \forall \alpha>0$$
Now we have

$$\frac {\sqrt {2n-1}~ \log (4n+1)} {n(n+1)}\sim_\infty \sqrt 2\frac{\ln(4n)}{n^{3/2}}=o\left(\frac1{n^{3/2-\alpha}}\right)$$
so it suffices to choose $\alpha>0$ such that $\frac32-\alpha>1$ to conclude that the given series is convergent.

Comment: $\sqrt 2\frac{\ln(4n)}{n^{3/2}}=o\left(\frac1{n^{3/2-\alpha}}\right)$. Could you please explain the steps after that?

Comment: If you choose $\alpha>0$ st $\frac{3}{2}-\alpha>1$ then $\sum \frac{1}{n^{3/2-\alpha}}$ converges so your series will also converge.

Answer (score 0):

For large $n$ $$\frac{\sqrt{2n-1} \hspace{1mm}\ln(4n+1)   }{  n(n+1)  }\approx \frac{\sqrt{2n} \hspace{1mm}\ln(4n)   }{  n(n+1)  }=\sqrt{2}\frac{\ln4n}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)}=\sqrt{2} \hspace{1mm} \ln4\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)}+\sqrt{2}\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}(n+1)}$$ The first term is the term from a convergent series.(Hint:- It is dominated by a convergent $p$-series). Now consider the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}n}$. We are done if we could show that this series converges. Integral test seems to be efficient in this case:-  \begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_1^{n}\frac{\ln x}{x\sqrt{x}} dx&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^{\ln n}ue^{-\frac{u}{2}}du \qquad (\mbox{where $u=\ln x$} )\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}ue^{-\frac{u}{2}}du \\
&=4
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}Thus $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\ln n}{n\sqrt{n}}$ converges. Since $\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n} (n+1)}<\frac{\ln n}{n\sqrt{n}}$, so by Comparison test the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n} (n+1)}$ converges. Ultimately, your series converges.